# send a pull request to a branch

Tags: git, svn, github

I want to propose a patch but the administrator asks me to send a pull request to a specific branch only.
How could I do?

Originally I follow the steps below:

```
0. Fork
1. git clone https://github.com/my/patch
2. cd patch
3. git checkout -b my-fix
4. do modify
5. git diff --word-diff
6. git commit -a -m 'It is my fix'
7. git push origin my-fix
```

For example, my target is https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer
& would like to send the pull request to branch dev-v2, instead of default branch release-v2.

Thanks~

Comment: If you need help in creating PR from forked repo to the base repo then this should help: https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-pull-request-from-a-fork/

Answer (score 0):

When you open pull requests it have an option to chose the branch to compare, see the screenshot below:
[image]

Comment: Why downvote?.  I am pretty sure that this is the only method that you can chose a branch...

Answer (score -1):

You should checkout the branch specified by the administrator once you clone your fork:

```
git checkout -b required-branch origin/required-branch
```

And make your changes to the code in that branch and then continue your workflow with commit and push.

**[UPDATE]**

Now I see that all mentioned branches are assigned to the same commit. Apparently you can change the branch your pull request is attached to on [github pull request page](https://github.com/blog/2224-change-the-base-branch-of-a-pull-request).